# Should I say "Quite a long time" or simply just "Quite a long" - in the following context?

Tags: sentence-construction, time

What is the appropriate phrase when saying the following sentence?

1) "**Quite a long time** I have been waiting for her to back"

2) "**Quite a long** I have been waiting for her to back"

I'm asking this question, because I know about the question "For how long are you here" that is the correct rather that "For how long **time** are you here"

Comment: You can say "quite a long time" or "quite long", but not "quite a long" without "time". Either way, that phrase feels unnatural at the beginning of the sentence. I'd say "I have been waiting quite a long time for her to get back", or "I've been waiting quite long for her to get back".

Answer (score 2):

If I may be so bold, I would say neither is correct.

Here is what I hear speakers say.

> I have been waiting for her to be back **for a long time**.
>
> I have been waiting for her to be back **for quite a while**.

In this context,  `quite` and `long` have the same meaning and would be redundant next to each other.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree that it's more common in speech for the two clauses to be reversed, but I don't agree that *quite* and *long* are redundant. In fact, the two together can be used for emphasis, with either "time" or "while": "I have been waiting for her to come back for quite a long time." "I have been waiting for her to come back for quite a long while." (I will say that "quite a while," w/o the "long", is a common and established idiom.)

Answer (score 1):

> Certain forms of AdjP occur right at the beginning of the NP, before
>   the indefinite article *a*:
>
> > [31]  i. a) [***How long* a delay**] will there be? (=> Here *How long* is an AdjP and in this AdjP the head adjective is *long* and
> >     modifier is *how*. The noun phrase where this AdjP occurs is *How long
> >     a time*)
> >     [31] ii. b) He'd chosen [***too dark* a colour**] (=> Here *too dark* is an AdjP and in this AdjP the head adjective is *dark* and
> >     modifier is *too*. The noun phrase where this AdjP occurs is *too dark
> >     a colour*)
> >
> > [32]  i. a) It seemed [***such* a bargain**] 
> >     [32] ii. b) [***What* a fool**] I was.
>
> One type are AdjPs containing *how, as, so, too, this* or *that* as
>   modifier, as in [i]. There are two adjectives that can appear by
>   themselves in this position: *such* and the exclamative word *what*,
>   shown in [ii].

<sub>**Source -** A Student's Introduction to English Grammar by Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum</sub>

That is why **For how long time** is incorrect. The correct one is **For how long a time**.

In your sentence -

> **Quite a long time** I have been waiting ....

**Quite** there is a PREDETERMINER. And hence it comes before the CENTRAL DETERMINER *a*.

The noun phrase here is - **Quite a long time**

The structure of this NP is -

> PREDETRMINER + CENTRAL DETERMINER + ADJECTIVE + HEAD NOUN

This is perfectly fine. It's correct to write or say **quite a long time**. Here it's the NP that is acting as an adverbial without the need of any preposition.

One the other hand the phrase **quite a long** is incorrect here. This is incorrect because there is no head noun there like it's other version.

In order for this phrase to be correct we need to take out that *a*. Then it will be an Adverb Phrase. And *quite* there is an adjective, a modifier to the head adverb - *long*.

[image]

<sub>**Source -** Macmillan Dictionary</sub>

Comment: The word "time" is not supposed to be without an article before it - like sky, water, and other non-count nouns? ("you wrote is correct to say: "long a time")

Comment: @Assiduous No I didn't mean that. All I meant is that it depends on the modifier of the adjective phrase. Please read my answer again, if any problem please ask me. I will try to clarify.